# How to make a div clickable, but don't want inside elements to look like links with Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I am working on a messaging feature for my project. Right now I am a little stuck on how to make a div clickable that would bring a user to the conversation tab.

Here is my code:

```
        <%= link_to conversation_messages_path(conversation) do %>
          <li>
            <div class="well row" id='conversation-well-row'>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <%= image_tag recipient.profile.avatar.url, class: 'conversation-index-avatar' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <h4><%= recipient.profile.first_name %> <%= recipient.profile.last_name %></h4>
                <h5 class="text-black-50">Last message preview</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        <% end %>
```

It makes makes my `<div class="well">` clickable, but it also makes everything else look like a link inside that div. How do i make a link out of the well only?

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBaMA.png).

[image: this]

I want the name, as well as  message preview, to be previewed just as text and also i want to make the avatar a link for profile.

Comment: What you actually want to do, please elaborate

Comment: Do you want the text not to look like a link or do you want it not to even work as a link? those are two different things.

Comment: I want the text to not look as a link and i want the picture to work as a different link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text to not look like a link, you need to apply CSS to the text.

For this purpose, add a class to the text:

```
<h4 class="no-link-style"><%= recipient.profile.first_name %> <%= recipient.profile.last_name %></h4>
<h5 class="no-link-style text-black-50">Last message preview</h5>
```

And in your CSS file, add CSS for this class:

```
.no-link-style {
    color: #000000 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;

}
```

use color code of your choice, #000000 is for black color

Answer (score 0):

For making your div clickable just add `clickable` class to and remove `well` class from it:

your code will look like:

```
<%= link_to conversation_messages_path(conversation) do %>
  <li>
    <div class="clickable row" id='conversation-well-row'>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <%= image_tag recipient.profile.avatar.url, class: 'conversation-index-avatar' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <h4><%= recipient.profile.first_name %> <%= recipient.profile.last_name %></h4>
        <h5 class="text-black-50">Last message preview</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Also add css in your css file as:

```
.clickable {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: This will only show a cursor like the link is clickable, but the text decoration of name and message preview will still remain like a link.